# AJAX Insert HTML with jquery opens infinite loop of new tabs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to use AJAX to open a new tab (page 2) based on an html template when a menu option is selected from my 'About' menu (page 1).  So, 'page 1' opens 'page 2' & the function inserts code into 'page 2'. The 'About' menu is a nav-bar unordered list.

The code I've written accesses a pre-published google doc.  I'm simply trying to insert the document into a  section in the template.

I've checked all of the intermediary steps. There are no errors & the document is returned as an HTML string.

First function, menuClick:

```
function menuClick(doclink) {

  window.open( 
            "AboutTemplate.html", "_blank");

  inject_to = $("content"); 
  load_from = "AboutTemplate.html"; 
  d = loadDoc(doclink, inject_to, load_from); }
```

Second function, loadDoc:

```
function loadDoc(doclink, inject_to, load_from) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    d = this.responseText;
  
    console.log("Inside loadDoc")
    console.log (inject_to + ", " + load_from)
    console.log("-----------------------------")
    console.log(d)
    $.get(load_from, d, function(d) {
      inject_to.html(d);
      })
    }
  }
  xhttp.open("GET", doclink, true);
  xhttp.send();}
```

Finally, the event handler, which references the menu id 'AboutPages':

```
$('AboutPages').click(menuClick())
```

When initiate this code, it goes into a loop that:

1. Continuously opens new tabs, rather than just one tab.
2. Does NOT insert the HTML into the newly opened tab.

As I said, I've verified that everything is being returned in the correct form from the google doc.  That is what the console log statements are in place to identify. I include them because I wonder if I have the ordering for this incorrect?

***UPDATE***  I've fixed the loop that opens multiple tabs.  The event handler was doing the same thing as the 'onclick' event I had included in each LI element.  So, I've eliminated the event handler.

I alse re-verified that Google docs is returning an HTML string.  It is.  So, I've got that.  I just can't determine the correct way to insert it into the newly opened page.

I tried this and it didn't work:

```
var p = window.open(load_from,"_blank")
```

and

```
p.getElementById('contents') = loadDoc(doclink, inject_to, load_from)
```

When I try to dimension the newly opened page as its own variable, it won't let me access any of the attributes that go with normally opening a window.

Comment: `$('AboutPages').click(menuClick())` **calls** the `menuClick()` function, and does not establish a "click" handler. In addition, doing an HTTP request and then immediately doing *another* HTTP request is curious, as is mixing jQuery and raw XHR.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove parenthesis, do not invoke your handler in place but instead to pass in as an argument:

```
$('AboutPages').click(menuClick())
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!  I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'invoke in place'.  Do you mean pass the entire event handler at the 'onclick' portion of the webpage?

Comment: Yes, just pass the handler into the `.click` method. Right now you invoking it and the `.click` method receives the value that returns from the `menuClick` function.

Comment: I really appreciate your help!  That solved the infinite opening tabs problem.  The HTML still is not finding its way to the inject_to location.  Right now, I've defined that as $('content').  Is $ referring to the correct page?  All of the errors are now gone, however.